# Text Size Ratio Between Mobile and Tablet Android

Tags: android, css

> What is recommended text size ratio between mobile and tablet device?

I am currently working on the application for  supporting different screen sizes .I am facing issue with text sizes ,after some reasearch , I found that  creating different values folder will solve my problem .

But I didn't know  multiplication ratio which I can use to best decide on text size for a `Tablet and 7"` Device  Screen .

**if have a text with size of `20SP` in  normal phone screen 
then what is the corresponding text size for tablet**

**How  can I calculate the corresponding value for tablet any formula ?**

Comment: http://stefan222devel.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-screen-densities-sizes.html

Comment: http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: if you have set `sp`, android automatically changes text size according to device screen